# Appending a value in PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, xml-parsing

Goal: To identify elements with specific values in an attribute and append the value of identified values with user input.

I have an XML file which multiple resource elements, some of which has XML values and some not. Below is an example.

```xml
<resources>
  <resource identifier="i149" href="items/i149/qti.xml">
    <file href="items/i149/qti.xml" />
  </resource>
</resources>
```

I am stuck as to how to append what I've identified. I'm currently using `SelectNodes()` to identify that any identifier value containing an `i` should be appended by with `$userInput`.   When I run it, though, I get this error:

> Cannot convert argument "0", with value: "_01a", for "AppendChild" to type "System.Xml.XmlNode": "Cannot convert the "_01a" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Xml.XmlNode"."

Instead of `SelectNodes()`, should I be getting the XML as a string?  Below is the code.

```bsh
#user prompt
$userInput = Read-Host -Prompt 'Insert 2 alpha-numeric'

#ims
$imsnodes = [xml](Get-Content $ims.FullName)
$identifier = $imsnodes.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@identifier,'i')]")
$identifier.AppendChild("_$userInput")
$imsnodes.Save($_.FullName)
```

The outcome I would like to have is below, where `XX = $userInput`:

```xml
<resources>
  <resource identifier="i149_XX" href="items/i149/qti_XX.xml">
    <file href="items/i149/qti_XX.xml" />
  </resource>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to append a string to an attribute value, not an XML node to another XML node (which is what the `AppendChild()` method does).

Change this:

```
$identifier = $imsnodes.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@identifier,'i')]")
$identifier.AppendChild("_$userInput")
```

into this:

```
$imsnodes.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@identifier,'i')]") | ForEach-Object {
    $_.identifier += "_$userInput"
}
```

and the problem will disappear.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Another quesion is, which method would work for editing the file name since this appends at the end no matter what?

`<file href="items/i149/qti_XX.xml" />` becomes `qti.xml_XX`. I tried using `$qti.Value = "new value"` but that replaces the entire value of the attribue instead of just appending qit with user input.

Comment: `$foo += 'bar'` is just syntactic sugar for `$foo = $foo + 'bar'`. You can always use `$var = $var <op> some_value`, e.g. `$_.identifier = $_.identifier -replace 'something', 'with other'`.